# Putting reveal.js presentation into a modal. How to target a slide, then open modal?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, reveal.js

I've created a page with a reveal.js presentation set up like a slider inside a modal that will be the basis for an online portfolio. There will be a bunch of thumbnails on the landing page, showing various projects. When you click on a thumb, it will open a modal and load the reveal slide for that project. Once inside the reveal slideshow, you can walk back and forth through the other projects, or you can close the modal, go back to the landing page, click on another thumb, and again be taken to the corresponding page in the slider for that project.

The problem I need help with is this: opening the modal and targeting a particular reveal slide are both done by clicking on links. I'm using the animatedModal.js plugin for the modal, and that uses a class and an id in the open link. Reveal slides are targeted with an id. How can I create a link that will pick the target reveal.js slide, and then open the modal?

I have a codepen example here: http://codepen.io/crizpeecritter/pen/BjvZWy
You will see that simply opening the modal takes you to whatever slide was last active. But if you click on one of the “Go to…” links first, that will load the corresponding slide, even though the modal is closed. Then when the modal opens, you are on the correct slide.

So what I need is a (I assume) a click hander with a link that will first load a particular slide, and then open the modal to reveal that slide. I’ve spent a few hours on this problem, but unfortunately I don’t yet know enough jquery to solve it. The final project will have, as I said, a bunch of thumbnails with links replacing the simple links I have in the example. Any help I can get with this will be very appreciated!

```
          $("#demo02").animatedModal({
            modalTarget: 'modal-02',
            animatedIn: 'slideInRight',
            animatedOut: 'slideOutLeft',
            color: '#3498db',
            // Callbacks
            beforeOpen: function() {
              console.log("The animation was called");
            },
            afterOpen: function() {
              console.log("The animation is completed");
            },
             beforeClose: function() {
              console.log("The animation was called");
            },
            afterClose: function() {
              console.log("The animation is completed");
            }
          });

        Reveal.initialize({

            transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom
            backgroundTransition: 'slide',
            viewDistance: 12,
            progress: false,
            slideNumber: true,
            embedded: true,

        });
```